# OpenLayers3 no refresh WMS in zoom-in

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have an aplication, made with OpenLayers 3, GeoServer and ReactJS, showing some WMS. And for a strange reason I can't manage to refresh the image when I zoom in ONLY if the screen resolution is wider that 1314px. It's very strange, if the resolution is for example 1310, I can do normally zoom-in and zoom-out and the wms got refreshed after every zoom, BUT, if the resolution is wider than 1315px, ONLY zoom out works, but not zoom in.

Any one had experimented something like this before?

This is how I'm calling the wms (ReactJS):

```
    var map = this.state.map;
    var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://spif.XX.XX:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:biodent_clientes'},
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        })
    });
    this.state.layersMaServer = wmsLayer;
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

There's no problem with GeoServer, the WMS are well loaded after every zoom-in or out, but I don't know why at zooming in isn't been refreshed on client side (broser). If I zoom-out just a little bit, then the image is refreshed with the correct wms, but why only under 1314px!

EDIT: The last logs of GeoServer:

https://paste.ofcode.org/32BP5Yvwi3JUsgugFnfPcdd

The first "event" (mouse scroll to zoom in) were made at 1314px wide, there's no problem on showing the wms. The last "event" was made at 1315px, there I can't make to OpenLayers to show the WMS, but they are correctly generated, I can see them on the Chrome Dev.

Comment: check the GeoServer log but you may be exceeding the size limits of the WMS request or the time limit. Try using tiles instead of a single image to avoid the issue

Comment: But why ONLY at specific wide size. As I said, if the screen is under 1315px wide, there's no problem at all at refreshing the image on zoom-in, and imagen could be have bigger in size (a png with lot of colors, it's a heat map) than a even transparent image but in a resolution bigger than 1315px.

Comment: If it is a dynamic image it could exceed the limits at lots of points, check the log

Comment: Ok, I'll check the logs (never did before), I'll comment here soon.

Comment: Ready, I edited my question, not it has some logs. I can't see anything weird there.

Comment: you don't seem to have changed the log level to debug, but it seems ok so it is probably a UI issue